# Syntax error on token ",", Expression expected after this token

Tags: java

I'm not that experienced with coding but I know a thing or two and when trying to do something I encountered a problem.

The code itself:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        folder test = new folder("test", [5] , [5] );
        int i = test.containedFolders.length;
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

The constructor:

```
public class folder
{

    private String name;
    private String[] containedFolders;
    private String[] containedFiles;

    folder(String Name, String[] ContainedFolders, String[] ContainedFiles)
    {
        name = Name;
        containedFolders = ContainedFolders;
        ContainedFiles = ContainedFiles;
    }
}
```

As seen in the title I get this error message- "Syntax error on token ",", Expression expected after this token" on both of the "," in ("test", [5] , [5] ).

Comment: `[5]` is not a valid array of strings

Comment: 1) Always, **always**, ALWAYS stick to Java naming conventions - especially if you claim to know "_a thing or two_" - classes are in `PascalCase`, variables are `camelCase`. 2) How exactly is `[5]` a) valid syntax or b) a `String[]`?

Answer (score 0):

Your folder class constructor

```
folder(String Name, String[] ContainedFolders, String[] ContainedFiles)
```

is expecting a string, then 2 string arrays.

so you want to write your constructor as:

```
folder test = new folder("test", new String[] {"5"}, new String[] {"5"} );
```

The difference between this one and yours is that Java uses curly braces {} to denote an array literal.  And you also need to put quotes around the 5's to denote them as strings.

Comment: This doesnt really work for me (could be me typing it somehow wrong but i think i managed to fix that by typing:
folder test = new folder("test", new String[5] , new String[5] );
Do you think it really solves it or just mess it in some different way?

btw thx for answering anyways!

Comment: `new String[] {"5"}` is an array of one string which is `"5"`. Yours is an uninitialized array of 5 strings which are `null`.

Comment: kichik is right, new String[5] just creates an empty array with 5 slots, new String[] {"5"} uses array literals to define a new array of strings with "5" in it.